# VMWare Not Starting even with Device Guard Disabled

Tags: windows-10, vmware

I have a weird issue that I am having trouble solving. I have been using *VMWare Workstation 15 Player 15.5.6 build-16341506* on *Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18363 N/A Build 18363* all week and suddenly today I am getting the below error when I try to start my VM (which was turned off normally last night).

> Your host does not meet minimum requirements to run VMware Player with Hyper-V or Device/Credential Guard enabled. Refer to VMware KB article 76918 at https://kb.vmware.com/kb/76918 for more details.

> Error while powering on: Transport (VMDB) error -14: Pipe connection has been broken.

I have had this before and the issue was just to set *Device Guard* to disabled and to turn off Hyper-V. I have done both of these, I even disabled *Windows Sandbox* and *Virtual Machine platform*.

Despite this and associated restarts, I am still getting the error.

The only changes I made to my system today were installing *MySQL Workbench* and *SQL Server 2019*.

Any idea what might still be causing this error?

The host system has 32GB RAM and a 10th Gen i7, I would think this would be sufficient in terms on requirements.

Please let me know any more info you need.

Comment: You should upgrade to 2004.  You won’t have to worry about the Hyper-V Device Guard conflict with the current version of VMWare Player.